# Функция преобразования long long в string

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите как можно преобразовать 16-значное число в `string`. Или для этого подойдет `itoa()` ?

Comment: Полагаю, будет уместно отметить, что функции `itoa` нет в стандарте.

Comment: Так в каком языке-то??? C++ или C? Почему два тэга на вопросе?

Comment: @AnT, как я понял по комментариям к своему ответу, все-таки C, но в итоге правильным отметили ответ с C++ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имеется перегруженная стандартная функция с именем `std::to_string`, которую вы можете использовать для преобразования целочисленных значений (и значений с плавающей точкой) в строку.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    long int x1 = -1;
    unsigned long int x2 = 2;
    long long int y1 = -3;
    unsigned long long int y2 = 4;

    std::string s = "Sequence of numbers: ";

    s += std::to_string( x1 ) + ", " + std::to_string( x2 ) + ", " + 
         std::to_string( y1 ) + ", " + std::to_string( y2 );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль следующий:

```
Sequence of numbers: -1, 2, -3, 4
```

Вот список этих функций

```
string to_string(int val);
string to_string(unsigned val);
string to_string(long val);
string to_string(unsigned long val);
string to_string(long long val);
string to_string(unsigned long long val);
string to_string(float val);
string to_string(double val);
string to_string(long double val);
```

Имейте в виду, что если вы работаете с MS VC++ 2010, то у вас могут быть проблемы с неоднозначностью вызова функции, так как эта функция в MS VC++ определена не для всех указанных в списке типов.

Узнать, сколько десятичных знаков может храниться в числе вы можете с помощью класса `std::numeric_limits`. Например, следующая программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long int>::digits10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long int>::digits10 << std::endl;
}
```

в зависимости от платформы, где запущена программа, может иметь следующий вывод на консоль:

```
18
18
```

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream sstream;
    std::string snum;
    long long num = 999L;

    sstream << num;
    sstream >> snum;  // или snum = sstream.str()

    std::cout << snum << std::endl;
}
```

Можно написать обобщенную функцию:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
std::string to_str(const T &obj)
{
    std::stringstream sstream;
    sstream << obj;
    return sstream.str();
}

int main()
{
    long long num = 999L;
    std::string snum = to_str(num);

    std::cout << snum << std::endl;
}
```

---

**Обновление**: пример на чистом C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    long long num = 999L;
    char snum[20];

    snprintf(snum, sizeof snum, "%lld", num);
    printf("%s\n", snum);
}
```

P.S. Все-таки, если хотите на чистом C, то не стоит писать в заголовке вопроса и в тегах "C++".

Comment: а чисто по-сишному ?

Comment: @neko69, если чисто по-сишному, то нужно менять теги у вопроса. А то я уже начал писать ответ с бустами, С++11 и прочими вариантами.

Comment: @neko69, обновил ответ.

Comment: @VadimShender error C3861: snprintf: идентификатор не найден VS 2008 Express. Полностью копировал вставил вашу программу.

Comment: @neko69, как оказалось, `snprintf` есть только в Visual Studio 2015 (проверить, к сожалению, не мог, Windows и VS нету). Сделайте так: `sprintf(snum, "%lld", num);`. По поводу `snprintf` вот: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915672/snprintf-and-visual-studio-2010.

Answer (score 1):

Для С++11 и старше самый простой вариант использовать функцию [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string ulonglongToStr(int64_t l, int base)
{
    char buff[67]; // length of MAX_ULLONG in base 2
    buff[66] = 0;
    char *p = buff + 66;
    const char _zero = '0';

    if (base != 10) {
        while (l != 0) {
            int c = l % base;

            --p;

            if (c < 10)
                *p = '0' + c;
            else
                *p = c - 10 + 'a';

            l /= base;
        }
    }
    else {
        while (l != 0) {
            int c = l % base;

            *(--p) = _zero + c;

            l /= base;
        }
    }

    return p;
}

std::string longlongtoStr(int64_t l, int base)
{
   std::string res = ulonglongToStr(l<0 ? -l: l, base);
   if (l < 0)
     res = "-" + res;
   return res;
}
```